# android drawable folder for large screens

Tags: android, android-layout

I have images in drawable-hdpi(big images) and in drawable-mdpi(small images)

I opened my app on Kindle fire (its get layout from layout-large) and it use images from
drawable-mdpi , is any way to let app to get images from drawable-hdpi when screen size is large?

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is to use [configuration qualifiers.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)

It seems you are really misunderstanding what these folders do.
Your android will select folder based on it's screen size or pixel-density.

Your Kindle Fire has a medium Pixel density and a large screen. So it selects its resources from the res folders with those given qualifiers.

res/layout-large/my_layout.xml

and images from

```
res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png
```

You cannot tell your kindle to get images from the hdpi folder because it does not have a high pixel density.

So you could either create a folder called

```
res/drawable-large-mdpi/
```

specifically for your Kindle Fire device.

Or just make sure the right images are in the right folders.

**EDIT: Size qualifiers are deprecated from 3.2.**

While deprecated, they still work. Although results may not be what expected (for example: 5" and 7" are seen as same size -large-which still have difference). So they added dp qualifiers to use beyond 3.2. Which are much better. developer.android.com/guide/practices/… It kinda works like media-queries

Comment: You can create a folder called drawable-large to let it get your images based on screen-size or drawable-large-mdpi for large screen with medium pixel density (which your kindle fire has). Which is bad practice because you should load images based on screen density.

Comment: thank you I understand now, I used res/drawable-large, drawable-small and drawable-normal to use images thanks

Comment: to find out what folder your device prefers, use an app called "ScreenInfo" it shows you the DPI and Screen Class for your device.

Comment: Size qualifiers are deprecated in 3.2 and above. Is res/drawable-large-mdpi exempt from this or do you have any alternatives for these versions?

Comment: While deprecated, they still work. Although results may not be what expected (for example: 5" and 7" are seen as same size -large-which still have difference).  So they added dp qualifiers to use beyond 3.2. Which are much better. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts  It kinda works like media-queries..

Comment: Hi @sturrockad I've just read thorugh the docs regarding the deprecated size qualifiers, but this seems to only relate to layouts and not drawables as far as I can tell?  I might be wrong but it seems that way......? :-/

Comment: It's only mentioned in the layout docs but I believe it refers to those qualifiers being deprecated throughout Android. More on the topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582600/xlarge-vs-sw720dp-screen-size-confusion

Answer (score 4):

Updating this with the new qualifiers for Android.

Use of size qualifiers such as `drawable-large` are deprecated in 3.2 or above.

To use the latest method of supporting multiple layouts and densities, you can use the following:

`res/drawable-sw600dp-mdpi`

In this example, sw600dp`represents the smallest width available to the activity in density-independent pixels,`600dp`in this case. This is deemed as being a little more fitting for device-specific layouts and drawables as the width is provided instead of a generalized size grouping such as`large`.

There are also new options for available width and height, full information available here: [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts)

Answer (score 3):

All qualifiers are processed in the order they appear in [Table2](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2).

Read [How Android Finds the Best-matching Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch).

Comment: I have to change drawable-hdpi to drawable-large-hdpi? it does not work

Comment: No change it to drawable-large-mdpi, because your Kindle Fire has large screen and medium density. (It does not have high desnity so it doesnt get it from the hdpi qualifier.